# Proving a statement in Well-formed formula language

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I'm trying to prove the following question:

> Prove that $\Sigma\subseteq WFF$ is a set so for every $\alpha,\beta\in WFF$, $\Sigma\models\left(\alpha\to\beta\right)$ or $\Sigma\models\left(\beta\to\left(\lnot\alpha\right)\right)$ if and only if for every $\gamma\in WFF$, $\Sigma\models\gamma$ or $\Sigma\models\lnot\gamma$.

I tried to start from $\Rightarrow$ part. Let there be $\Sigma$ so for every $\alpha,\beta\in WFF$, $\Sigma\models\left(\alpha\to\beta\right)$ or $\Sigma\models\left(\beta\to\left(\lnot\alpha\right)\right)$. Let $\gamma\in WFF$. Now I want to split into cases but not sure if the cases should be $\Sigma\models\left(\alpha\to\beta\right)$ and $\Sigma\models\left(\beta\to\left(\lnot\alpha\right)\right)$. Assuming that I used those two cases, I says that if $\Sigma\models\left(\alpha\to\beta\right)$ then for every $z$ so $z\models\Sigma$ you get $z\models\left(\alpha\to\beta\right)$ (by definition). But how to continue from here?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: take $\alpha$ to be a true sentence, e.g., $\forall x(x = x)$, and take $\beta$ to be a given WFF $\gamma$. Then see if you can simplify $\alpha \to \beta$ and $\beta \to \lnot \alpha$.